# Javascript number 0 showing as undefined

Tags: javascript

I am doing a JS challenges and while working ran into the number zero showing as undefined.

Zero only shows undefined when it comes second in the equation and will do this for add,subtract, divide or multiply.

Ex:

```
zero(plus(three())) // 3
three(plus(zero())) // Undefined
```

Is there a deeper reasoning for this? I am confused why it shows undefined 1 way but not the other. I also tried swapping

```
function zero(arg) {
  let num = 0;
  if(!arg) {return num;}
  if(arg.symbol == "+") {return num + arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "-") {return num - arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "*") {return num * arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "/") {return Math.floor(num / arg.param)}
}
function one(arg) {
  let num = 1;
  if(!arg) {return num;}
  if(arg.symbol == "+") {return num + arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "-") {return num - arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "*") {return num * arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "/") {return Math.floor(num / arg.param)}
}
function two(arg) {
  let num = 2;
  if(!arg) {return num;}
  if(arg.symbol == "+") {return num + arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "-") {return num - arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "*") {return num * arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "/") {return Math.floor(num / arg.param)}
}
function three(arg) {
  let num = 3;
  if(!arg) {return num;}
  if(arg.symbol == "+") {return num + arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "-") {return num - arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "*") {return num * arg.param}
  if(arg.symbol == "/") {return Math.floor(num / arg.param)}
}

function plus(arg) {
  if(!arg) {return "+";}
  let method = {param: arg, symbol: "+"}
  return method;
  }
function minus(arg) {
  if(!arg) {return "-";}
  let method = {param: arg, symbol: "-"}
  return method;
  }
function times(arg) {
  if(!arg) {return "*";}
  let method = {param: arg, symbol: "*"}
  return method;
  }
function dividedBy(arg) {
  if(!arg) {return "/";}
  let method = {param: arg, symbol: "/"}
  return method;
  }
```

Comment: Well what does `zero()` return? Then, what does `plus(zero())` return? Then, what does `three(plus(zero()))` return? To focus on the crucial point, what does `!0` evaluate to? How about `!3`?

Comment: You neet to check `typeof(arg) === 'undefined' `

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe for the simple debug walkthrough. I guess I really needed another pair of eyes on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obviously
it returns undefined because of this part

```
function plus(arg) {
     if(!arg) {return "+";}
     let method = {param: arg, symbol: "+"}
     return method;
 }
```

when `zero()` called without params, in `plus(arg)` should return "+"
because `!0 = true` and the first condition is executed
that's why when `zero()` is called without params, it would be undefined

Answer (score 2):

`zero()` returns `0`, `plus(0)` returns `"+"`, `three("+")` evaluates `"+".symbol` which is `undefined` because a string has no property called `symbol`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the values with a function which returns either the value or a function which is handed over as parameter.

```js
const
    numberFunc = value => f => f ? f(value) : value,
    zero = numberFunc(0),
    three = numberFunc(3),
    plus = a => b => a + b;

console.log(zero(plus(three())));
console.log(three(plus(zero())));
console.log(three());
console.log(zero());
```